# Major issues trying to run react native, expo, vs code, android studio

Tags: react-native, android-studio, expo

I am brand new to React-Native and have been consistently having major issues getting things up and running. I am using VS Code, Expo, Chrome, and Android Studio. I have encountered at least a dozen major issues trying to get a simple "Hello World" app running and none of the solutions to the particular problems has really worked leading me to believe there is a bigger issue going on. I'll try to run through a few of the issues I've had so far but as I said I'm totally new to this so I can't really understand/remember every issue that has come up.

I have consistently had issues getting metro bundler/expo and the Android Virtual Devices connecting. Sometimes they work, but most of the time I get the warning message "Couldn't adb reverse: device 'adb' not found" followed by the error message "Couldn't start project on Android: Error running adb: device 'adb' not found." If the device does work, if I try to reload from the developer menu or debug from the developer menu, expo crashes on the virtual device. Often I get a blank white screen and the developer menu will no longer open. I've had occasional success stopping the virtual device, restarting it, closing all expo windows, and trying to "run on android" from metro bundler. When this doesn't work, I've tried wiping the virtual device. Sometimes this works. Most often I have to delete the device and create a new one.

When I tried to run the debugger in Chrome, the times it appeared to work, I got console screens that didn't match any guides I've found online. Trying to force errors to understand the Chrome debugger completely crashed the virtual device. Had to close VS Code, Chrome, and delete the virtual device to be able to even begin again.

When I tried to follow guides to debug in VS Code I couldn't get that to work either. Regardless if I put in break points or not when I tried to run "attach to packager" it wouldn't output anything but I could hear my machine running really hard and VS Code seemed like it was trying to do something. I would have to close VS Code to get it working again. The other issue I would get an error telling me that Packager was running outside of VS Code. I would try to close down Android Studio and restart and I would get the same error. One time I almost got it working but the virtual device completely crashed and started flashing a white screen and had to be deleted.

I've had tons of other random errors that have only happened once or twice including some warning message about the binary of the android devices being obsolete or something like that.

Anyone have any idea what could be causing all of this? I've been dealing with this for almost two weeks and it has become incredibly frustrating.

Comment: this is not a post that is well suited for stackoverflow. you may be better off posting to https://forums.expo.io

1. for "error running adb" see solutions in https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/694
2. not clear what you mean about console screens when debugging, you'll need to elaborate on that in your post to forums
3. vs code integration issue seems like it's worth asking the vscode-react-native team about, eg: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-react-native/issues/408.

Comment: @brentvatne Thanks for the expo forums suggestion. I will try there as well. As I tried to explain in my post, I have tried solutions to the individual issues, including the two links you included, without success. This is what is leading me to believe there is a bigger issue. I am wondering why you suggest that "this is not a post that is well suited for stackoverflow"? I was hoping someone might suggest a bigger picture issue or train of thought to explore so that I might get past this phase.